# I think that because of my sins, my dua may not be getting accepted

Tags: dua, sin, tawba, forgiveness, depression

Assalam-O-Alaikum Wrwb,
I am a young Muslim man and I have found out that I have been "repenting and then repeating." By this, I mean I have been committing sin (I am abhorred to admit that I have watched some innapropiate things online) and then seeking forgiveness from My Lord, then for a while I stop that sin, but eventually I repeat the same sin. Often times I find myself depressed and extremely sad that I don't have the willpower to stop doing that sin and to stop lust, and I often think that because of my sinning, none of my dua have been accepted. This has been going on for around a year or possibly more. I've been making the same dua for that long time, but I've been sinning at the same time. Can somebody please give some guidance and help.
Please make dua for my guidance, mercy from Allah (SWT,) the ability to stop watching, and for my dua to get accpeted.
Jazakallah Khair.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you to get your answer. [Here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34878/if-sins-invalidate-dua-isnt-it-impossible-for-our-duas-to-be-answered)

We all knows Allah is **Ghafoor and Raheem**. If we even make sins 100 times and everytime we seek for forgiveness and repent from ALLAH. He will forgive us and accept our repent. He loves when someone return to ALLAH and seek forgiveness.